# spec.ts Exceeds maximum line length of 140

Tags: angular, jasmine, tslint

I am having unit test spec file for an Angular2 component.
This spec file import files/components like 

`import { DeviceProtocolModifiedLabelComponent } from
'../../../../../src/app/device/deviceProtocol/deviceProtocolList/deviceProtocolWidget/deviceProtocolModifiedLabel/device-protocol-modified-label.component';
import { DeviceProtocolTagsComponent } from
'../../../../../src/app/device/deviceProtocol/deviceProtocolList/deviceProtocolWidget/deviceProtocolTags/device-protocol-tags.component';`

But above lines crosses 140 characters in a line and gives below error on console.

`test/specs/app/device/deviceProtocol/device-protocol.component.spec.ts[25, 1]: Exceeds maximum line length of 140`

I gone through [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21868675/jquery-d-ts-compilation-failed-tslint-exceeds-maximum-line-length/21877187#21877187) question, but didn't help. I don't want to change configuration

Comment: Have you seen [the flags](https://palantir.github.io/tslint/usage/rule-flags/)? Btw, it would make sense to have re-exporting `index.ts` at some level of this path.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know I am very late to reply on this question on stackoverflow. But If anybody is looking for answer of this question (like me), so here are the solutions -

```
    1. Write your code in this way -
     import { 
        DeviceProtocolTagsComponentA, 
        DeviceProtocolTagsComponentB, 
        DeviceProtocolTagsComponentC 
     } from
    '../../../../../../../../../../../../device-protocol-tags.component';
    
    2. OR Go to tslint.json file and change this -
       "max-line-length": [
          true,
          140  // increase this value
        ]

    3. OR Add below line just above your code, like this -

       // tslint:disable-next-line:max-line-length
       import { DeviceProtocolModifiedLabelComponent } from  '../../../../../src/app/device/deviceProtocol/deviceProtocolList/deviceProtocolWidget/deviceProtocolModifiedLabel/device-protocol-modified-label.component';
```